# How to apply the following with less time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello is there a way to apply this with less time the query is taking too long time its 15 mins now and still executing

```
DELETE FROM [1] WHERE PHONE IN(

 SELECT PHONE FROM [2]
 WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2019-03-04' AND '2019-03-22'
 UNION  
 SELECT PHONE FROM [3]

)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
DELETE one FROM [1] one
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [3] three
              WHERE three.phone = one.phone
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [2] two
              WHERE one.phone = two.phone AND
                    two.call_date BETWEEN '2019-03-04' AND '2019-03-22'
             );
```

And index on `[2](phone, call_date)` and `[3](phone)` is then recommended.

Comment: . . . [3] is table name not row value. So, You would need other `exists`.

Comment: Curious: How does `SELECT PHONE FROM [3]` translate to `WHERE PHONE = 3`?

Comment: @tonypdmtr . . . I misread the question.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: And index on `[1](phone)` ?

Comment: @kobik . . . I don't think that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with `EXISTS` with `OR` instead of `UNION` :

```
DELETE o 
FROM [1] o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [2] t
              WHERE o.phone = t.phone AND
                    t.call_date >= '2019-03-04' AND t.call_date <= '2019-03-22'
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [3] tr WHERE tr.phone = o.phone);
```